# Pigeonhole Principle to solve question straightforward

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

A store wants to celebrate its anniversary and will give a $200 shopping certicate to the first customer to enter the store whose birthday is the same as that of two other previously admitted customers.

Also, there are extra prizes of $5,000 that will be for the first two customers that have consecutive birthday dates.

(a) What is the greatest possible number of customers that will enter the store before the $200 winner is announced?

(b) What is the greatest possible number of customers that will enter before the winners for the $5000 is announced?

For part a, I got 732 customers, and I applied the Pigeonhole principle. But for part b, I am thinking that it will be infinite because I don't know how many customers will enter the store.

Answer (score 2):

(a) It may indeed happen that there are $2\times 366=732$ customers before the $733$rd enters and wins.

(b) is a bit ambiguous: Are 1 March and 28 February consecutive? Are 31 December and 1 January consecutive? If we arrange the $366$ dates on a circle, we can pick at most $183$ of them with gaps between, so the answer should be $183$ (and the $184$th wins together with some other customer).

Comment: Lets say that the year has 366 days, just in case. I am also assuming that Dec 31st and Jan 1st are consecutive.

Comment: Dont you have to add 1 more to the 183 for Dec 31 and Jan 1?

Comment: Another thing.. if the first customer is on Dec 31, next Dec 30, and so on.. There would be 366 customer before there is a winner. Right?
This question of very ambiguous!!!! I totally agree!
I think you are assuming id everything goes right, 183 will be least customers to enter. 
But if they keep coming up randomly there are changes that we won't have a winner, and so it could be infinitely, since we are looking for the greatest possible number of customers.